# How would I word this in object oriented terms?

Tags: oop

If you have a class that authenticates a user and then the API you're using changes its authentication method, you would rewrite the authentication class.

**My question is what would you call creating code in in this pattern of "modularizing an operation" in this case authenticating a user?** I feel like this is a design pattern, but I can't think of the one or is this just a benefit of smart design with object oriented programming?

Comment: extracting a Interface for the authentication method and using this instead of the implementing class everywhere? (I would do something like this anyway to enable testing other parts of your system using the authetication - but *rewriting* parts of your code (or are you using another class?) is not really a pattern

Comment: Providing an authentication interface to the client that still the same even if the internal implementation was changed is a principle of the object oriented programming not a design pattern.

Comment: @BSH That wording made it much clearer, not sure why I got so confused. Thanks! post this as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the mode of authentication is not interchangeable at runtime, you're talking about the [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) design pattern. Otherwise, the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.